# Topological sort of subset of vertices of digraph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory, directed-graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am writing a program in C# 4.0 that I've abstracted to the following (I mention the language so that you know what libraries I have to work with; no third-party libraries):

---

Let `S = { s1, s2, s3, ..., sn }`.

For all `si`, `sj` in `S`, `i != j`, function `f(si, sj)` is an element of `{ true, false }`.  Calling this function `f` is quite expensive and should be done as few times as possible, however.

Given set `T = { t1, t2, t3, ..., tm }` a non-empty subset of `S`, compute a sequence `U = u1, u2, u3, ..., uo` which contains all the elements of `T` such that `f(ui, uj) == false` for all `i < j`, and `f(ui, s') == false` for all `i` and `s'` in `S - U`.  You may assume such a sequence exists.

---

Although this is in no way related to school (it's for work), I'd *prefer* the least amount of help to get me to the most optimal solution you can think of, so that I can learn more :)

---

Hints (some stuff I've thought about:)

1. **You need to visit each node at least once.**  Consider the case of `T = { t }` and `f(t, s') == false` for  all `s'` in `S - T` and `|S| >= 2`.  Once, in this case, is also sufficient.
2. Minimally `U` must be computed.  This computation can be represented by the following:  An `|S|x|S|` adjacency matrix with entries of

   - `?` : I don't know
   - `1` : Depends on.
   - `0` : Does not depend on.
   - `-` : I don't care.

Consider this (I'm walking myself through an example to see if there's a pattern to the optimal potential check sequences to help develop an algorithm).  `S = { a, b, c, d, e }`  `T = { a, b, c }` (signified by the stars):

```
     a  b  c  d  e
   ----------------
*a | -  -  -  ?  ?
*b | -  -  -  ?  ?
*c | -  -  -  ?  ?
 d | -  -  -  -  ?
 e | -  -  -  ?  -
```

`U = { a, b, c }` initially.  The diagonals are `-` because `f` is not defined when its operands are equal.  Since `a`, `b` and `c` are already in the set, it doesn't matter if anyone depends on them, hence `-`.

`f(a, d)`, `f(a, e)`, `f(b, d)`, `f(b, e)`, `f(c, d)`, `f(c, e)` are all equal candidates due to the symmetries.  Suppose we choose `f(a, d)` and it returns false.  Our table now looks like this:

```
     a  b  c  d  e
   ----------------
*a | -  -  -  0  ?
*b | -  -  -  ?  ?
*c | -  -  -  ?  ?
 d | -  -  -  -  ?
 e | -  -  -  ?  -
```

Case 1: `U = { a, b, c }`

To find this out, we could do it in 3 checks, if we got lucky, by checking the `f(b, d)`,  `f(c, d)` and `f(e, d)` and having them all be `false`.

Case 2: `U = { a, b, c, d, e }`

To find this out, we could do it in 2 checks, if we got lucky, by checking `f(b, d)` and `f(a, e)` and having them both return `true`.

*(I haven't thought these through, completely, yet, and I need to go eat.  Thanks to everyone reading!)*

Case 3: `U = { a, b, c, d }`

Case 4: `U = { a, b, c, e }`

Comment: I don't understand why someone would flag this as not a real question...?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, either.  I'm writing up an example right now.  (I presume the same individual downvoted it and Saul.  :/)

Comment: I re-added the condition about elements of `U` not depending on any elements of `S` that aren't in `U`, since that seems to have been lost in your rephrase. Also, a question: is `f` transitive?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!  `f(si, sj)` is a directed edge look-up, essentially.  If we have graph `G({ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 12, 23 })`, then it is the case that `f(1,2) == true` and `f(2,3) == true`.  `f(1,3) == false`, so if I understood you correctly `f` is not transitive.  If my `T = { 1 }`, my `U = { 1, 2, 3 }`, though, because `12` requires `2` to be included and `23`, then requires `3` to be included.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to continue thinking about this because I think it's interesting, but I'm not overly optimistic that you'll be able to save too many evaluations of `f`; at a minimum, you'll need to check `f` from each node in `U` to each node in `S - U` (`o (n-o)` checks), and probably also each element in `U` to its successors (`o (o-1) / 2` checks), for an `on - o^2/2 - o/2` lower bound.

Comment: Ok, i can now comment on posts, first I didn't downvote the question or my answer, i also think is an interesting problem, second put with all the fancy math you want, the problem is simple, don't discard my solution so fast, i know this problem (since I was like 15 yo) and solved that way, if done correctlly it won't take long to get the answer (unless you have millions of nodes or connections)... good luck

Comment: I didn't mean to think your solution wasn't valid in terms of correctness.  It just seemed like there may be a better run time to do it in.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

What i understood was that you want all the nodes you can visit starting from any node in a subset T... If this is what you mean you can try this...

1. Fill a Dictionary with all your nodes (with the node as Key and a bool visited as value (start this value as false))
2. Fill a Queue with your nodes in the subset T (as you add them search them in the dictionary and mark them as visited)
3. Pick the first element in the Queue check wich nodes can you visit from it, search if visited in the dictionary, if visited skip, if not, add them to the Queue and set them as visited, remove the first element of the Queue
4. Repeat 3 until you have no items in the queue

Your subset of Nodes you can visit starting from t is the ones you marked in the Dictionary

Hope it helps...

Comment: That looks like a BFS?  The problem is this step: `Pick the first element in the Queue check wich nodes can you visit from them`.  At the beginning I will have to check this node against all others.  I don't know, initially, given a Node, all its neighbors.  That's something I need to compute.

Comment: Maybe, if this is a graph i assume you not only have nodes, you also have connections, you will search wich connections start in the node X and add all the endindgs of those connections, having the connections order by node will help

Comment: Or, again, using a dictionary, with the starting node as the key and an array of all the ending nodes as the value like this
Connections
a -> b
a -> c
a -> f
b -> e
b -> h ....
Make a dictionary like this
[key:a, value:{b,c,f}],[key:b, value:{e,h}]...

Comment: @saul672 You seem to not be addressing the "perform as few checks as possible" (for node dependencies) part of the question. OP doesn't already have a graph structure; finding the edges is (as stated) expensive.

Comment: Sorry, I just realize my mistake i should've wrote `Pick the first element in the Queue check wich nodes can be visited from "IT"`, sorry about my english, this happens me a lot

Comment: @Dougal Well i don't know if this is known or just a comment `Each Node is either dependent or not dependent on every other distinct Node (a Node is not dependent on itself).` If it is known and you arange this information in a dictionary it won't be necessary to check all the nodes everytime, just when you are checking that node, and the `check if visited` before adding a node to the queue is fundamental to check a node only once